# Regex to not match leading and trailing white spaces for email address in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, material-ui

Currently, I use this email regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/
```

I try to validate the email like below:

```
 if (!event.target.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/)) {
     setEmailStatus('Enter valid email address');
 }
```

But when entering with trailing and leading spaces it doesn't throw any error.
e.g.     `hello@gmail.com`

How to validate the spaces for the above regex?

Here is the complete code:

```
const [ usernamevalues, setUsername ] = React.useState({ username: '' });
const [ emailvalues, setEmail ] = React.useState({ email: '' });
const [ usernameStatus, setUsernameStatus ] = React.useState('');
const [ emailStatus, setEmailStatus ] = React.useState('');

const handleChangeEmail = (prop) => (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.value.length === 0) {
        setEmailStatus('This field is required');
    } else if (!event.target.value.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/)) {
        setEmailStatus('Enter valid email address');
    } else {
        setEmailStatus('');
    }

    /*if (validator.isEmpty(event.target.value)) {
        setEmailStatus('This field is required');
    }*/

    setEmail({ ...emailvalues, [prop]: event.target.value });
};
```

Based on the errors, I'm trying to enable submit button. I'm maintaining state for the above fields.

```
let isEnabled = usernamevalues.username !== '' && usernamevalues.username.length >= 1
  && emailvalues.email !== '' && usernameStatus !== 'This field is required' && usernameStatus !== 'Enter valid username'
  && emailStatus !== 'This field is required' && emailStatus !== 'Enter valid email address'

<TextField
        label='Email'
        id='outlined-margin-normal'
        placeholder='Email'
        value={emailvalues.email}
        type='email'
        className={classes.textField}
        margin='normal'
        variant='outlined'
        onChange={handleChangeEmail('email')}
        InputLabelProps={{
            classes: {
                root: classes.cssLabel,
                focused: classes.cssFocused
            }
        }}
        InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position='end'>
                <EmailOutlinedIcon htmlColor='#1C5FAB' opacity={0.5} />
            </InputAdornment>
        ),
        classes: {
            root: classes.cssOutlinedainput,
            focused: classes.cssFocused,
            notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
            input: classes.input
        }
    }}
    error={emailStatus ? emailStatus : ''}
    helperText={emailStatus !== '' ? emailStatus : null}
/>
<Typography className={classes.error}>{error}</Typography>
<Button
    variant='outlined'
    className={classes.button}
    onClick={handleSubmit}
    disabled={!isEnabled}
    style={{ backgroundColor: isEnabled ? '#1c60ab' : '#DCE2EB'}}
>
    Submit
</Button>
```

Comment: This means there is some `.trim()` between the string initialization and the regex `match()`. Is it Angular?

Comment: try adding \S in the end like `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\S$/`

Comment: I'm using react

Comment: Then show all relevant code please.

Comment: Added the code snippet

Comment: Have you tried updating the regex provided in my earlier comment, that will throw the error in case of trailing or leading spaces.

Comment: I tried, it is not working.

Comment: That's because need to add /S in the start as well so updated regex is `^\S+[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\S$`..update the regex tester [here](https://regex101.com/r/oaKGGO/3)

Comment: @Vishal you're trying to make white spaces be accepted yet what OP wants is the reverse

Comment: @Tibebes.M  \S+ matches any non-whitespace character so adding it in beginning and at the end should not allow any whitespace.

Comment: @Vishal even worse.. try "`.^#$%,;s@gmail.com`" then - https://regexr.com/5jsjt

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, in that case we can use a negated set of special characters in the beginning like  `^([^<>()[\]\,;:\s@\"\.])+[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$` and add any special character in the set we want to ignore like if we want to ignore * just add `\*` in the set

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex. Use `trim()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim))

using your example:

```
if (!event.target.value.trim().match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/)) {
     setEmailStatus('Enter valid email address');
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is not solving the issue. It is the source of issue.

Comment: @grreeenn please read the line "_when entering with trailing and leading spaces **it doesn't throw any error**_"

Comment: @Tibebes.M I assume that trimming useless characters instead of throwing errors on invisible stuff is much more user-friendly. This one will solve the problem, not the fact that error is not thrown. Unless, of course, it's some sophisticated user test on email format knowledge

Comment: you should suggest that to OP in the question's comments section then. The answers section should address what's being asked!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let email = event.target.value.trim();
if (!email.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/)) {
     setEmailStatus('Enter valid email address');
}
```